# How to practice SSH with single Ubuntu system?

Tags: ssh

I am having only one Ubuntu installed PC and I must practice SSH. could somebody help me how can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: "Practice SSH" is a vague request. Do you mean practicing how to administrate an SSH server? You only need one Ubuntu PC for that - you can connect to it from any other computer with an SSH client (such as PuTTY for Windows). Do you mean practicing forwarding ports? Then you will want to use a remote server or run your own in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

1. build a virtual machine on that Ubuntu PC or
2. build a server in the cloud

to which you can SSH to. There are a few cloud services that offer 30 to 90-day trial like [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/free/), [Cloud Linux](http://www.cloudlinux.com) and [HP Cloud](http://www.hpcloud.com/free-trial)

Comment: can you explain the process too, thank you for answering.

Comment: I mean process of connecting to any cloud server. That can help me  as a tutorial.

Comment: Once your cloud server is ready, you can do the steps to secure it as outlined here http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-essentials-3-basic-cloud-server-security

Comment: @J.AustinRodriguez Link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Define the ssh keys (used for the communication between the masters and slaves):

```
`ssh-keygen -t rsa`   (Use empty responses for each prompt)  
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):   
Enter same passphrase again:   
Your identification has been saved in: `/home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa`   
Your public key has been saved in `/home/user-name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

`cd /home/user-name/.ssh`  
`cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys`
```

Note: You need to copy the authorized_keys file into the corresponding .ssh folder of each node.

And then you are done. ssh localhost

Comment: Since OP didnt mention what he means by practise, I thought he is having trouble initiating a session on localhost. ^(to all those people, who gonna think, this is not a valid answer)